# how to use java mail services on linux with proxy

Tags: java

I am in a network with proxy 192.168.1.1
when i am implementing the java mail i am getting error network not connected though i have configured the proxy also in the program.

```
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");      
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
props.put("proxyHost", "192.168.1.1");
props.put("proxyPort", "8080");
```

Comment: is [this][1] the answer to your question?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130939/send-an-email-from-java-through-proxy/5130962#5130962